# MongoDB. Модификация нескольких объектов

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Необходимо инкрементировать сразу несколько записей в документе в Mongo.
т.е. имеется объект вида

```
{"_id" : 1, "arr" : [ { "el1" : 5 }, { "el2" : 10 } ] }
```

Есть ли способ сразу инкрементировать обе записи в массиве arr?
или как нибудь пересобрать документ таким образом, что бы это стало возможно.
Например

```
{"_id" : 1, "el1" : 5, "el2" : 10 }
```

И ещё загвоздка в том, что нужно не только инкрементировать знечения всех полей, но и добавить новые, если в запросе они указаны.

Т.е. если есть документ вида

```
   {"_id" : 1, "el1" : 5, "el2" : 10 }
```

и в запросе на апдейт пришёл документ вида

```
{"el1" : 1, "el2" : 1, "el3" : 1 }
```

то счетчики el1 и el2 увеличиваются, а el3 создается в документе с единицей.

Прошу подсказать способы решения задачи, если это возможно. 
Структура документа и запроса не строгая. Всё подстрою под решение задачи.

Comment: Поля `el1, el2, el3` динамичные?

Comment: нет. 
но проблему мне уже помогли решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Избавился от массива в документе и переписал данные в коллекции таким образом

```
{ "_id" : "test_id_1", "docs" : { "el_1" : 1, "el_2" : 1 } }
```

После этого вызываю метод update для коллекции (node.js - mongodb)

```
db.collection.update(
   { "_id" : "test_id_1" }, 
   { $inc: 
      {"docs.el_1":1,
       "docs.el_2":1,
       "docs.el_3":1
      }
   },
   {
     "upsert" : true 
   }
);
```

Таким образом, те ключи в docs, которые нужно инкрементировать - инкрементируются, а новые ключи создаются со значением 1.
И если документа с нужным _id нет, то он так же создается.